# Ansible: how to compare prompt var inside include?

Tags: ansible

```
  vars_prompt:

   - name: "x"
     prompt: "Enter abc "

   tasks:

      - include: 'tasks/abc.yml'
        when: {{ x }} == "abc"             #   ----->syntax error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add moustaches to `when`. The problem has nothing to do with prompt.

The correct syntax is:

```
when: x == "abc"
```